# Fetch_Feed cURL error 28

Tags: feed

So whenever I try to use fetch_feed with urls like the one below, I get back *"WP HTTP Error: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 30070 milliseconds with 0 bytes received"* However when I use just a plain cURL on the url get a response. So I can only conclude something in Fetch Feed is the issue. Anyone have a better idea how to get past this issue?

```
include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php' );
$feed_url = 'https://www.cbc.ca/podcasting/includes/frontburner.xml';
$rss = fetch_feed( $feed_url );
var_dump($rss);
```

Edit: I did some digging in the fetch_feed function, and found it worked when I commented out

```
$feed->set_file_class( 'WP_SimplePie_File' );
```

Any reason that could be? Any way to make this change in the theme file so it's not changed when wordpress is updated?

Comment: Strange behaviour.. can you try to filter CURL settings like https://stackoverflow.com/a/54583058/591486 to see if they help resolve this?

Comment: I did try that and it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's just us, but it seems like you need to set a user agent other than the default which is stored in the `SIMPLEPIE_USERAGENT` constant, and with `fetch_feed()`, you can use the [`wp_feed_options` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_feed_options/) to set a custom user agent — or none also worked for me.

Working example:

```php
add_action( 'wp_feed_options', function ( $feed ) {
    $feed->set_useragent( 'MyPlugin/1.0' );              // works
    $feed->set_useragent( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ); // works
    $feed->set_useragent( '' );                          // empty; worked for me..

    // You can also try increasing the timeout, but the default one (10 seconds)
    // worked fine for me.
    $feed->set_timeout( 15 );
} );
```

Comment: Looks like this worked. Is that user agent set in `$feed->set_file_class( 'WP_SimplePie_File' );`? It also worked when I commented out that line.

Comment: Yes, and you may also override the file class the same way WP did it. E.g. Clone the [`WP_SimplePie_File` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_simplepie_file/) then set the user agent directly in your class without using `$feed->set_useragent()`.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! This solved an issue that's been persistent for 2 years.